# Roomdatabase instance costs

Tags: android, android-room

Has anyone actually measured costs of creating multiple room dbs, say per-feature?

I've come across this:

> If your app runs in a single process, you should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object. Each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances within a single process.

In case of a multi-module project it brakes encapsulation by forcing specification of all entities used inside **@Database(entities = [..** Or, perhaps, there is a workaround?

I've tried googling a solution and didn't anything

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying creating multiple `RoomDatabase` in a single process can have performance implications as each database instance requieres some overhead for initialization and management, but the real cost will depend on :

1. Sinze and complexity
2. Number of threads accessing on it
3. Availability of resources of your mobile

What you can do is create a module which contains the `database` and then in all of your `features` you create the entities and DAOs for each module in separate classes and include them in the database.

I recommend to you to use a single `database` in case you do at least one of the points I said before and structure your entities and DAOs in a way that allows for modularization and separation of concerns so it can help you to improve the maintainability and performance of your app.